# Big O complexity of set(l) where l is a list

Tags: python, string, list, set

What is the Big O complexity for set(l) where l is a list or set(s) where s is a string?

```
  l=[1,2,3,1]
  m=set(l)  #m=[1,2,3]
  s="abca"
  t=list(s) #t=['a','b','c']
```

New-ish to Python and couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: well, I googled "python complexity of creating a set" and found this exact duplicate. This question is a nice, fundamental question, that's why it's already been asked here.

Comment: My bad. I missed the word "creating"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of language, it should be O(n).

Dictionary or Hashset lookup and/or insertion is O(1). Therefore, you just loop over the original list (or string) and insert into the set one by one. This give you O(n).

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over a list is O(n) and adding each element to the hash set is O(1), so the total operation is O(n).